# How to get route parameters in the AngularDart component in my view?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-router

In AngularDart, how can I get the route parameters from within my component which is in a view?

As far as I have managed to get is that in my router, I believe I should add parameters as such:

```
'class': ngRoute(
    path: '/class/:year/:month/:day',
    view: 'views/class.html'
),
```

Then how can I get the year month and day in my component? its a @Component annotated class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should work

```dart
@Component(...)
class MyComponent {
  RouteProvider _routeProvider;

  MyComponent(this._routeProvider);

  var year = _routeProvider.parameters['year'];
  ...
}
```

You let inject the `RouteProvider` and access the parameters map.

Answer (score 0):

I think the current answer is obsolete.

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_router/angular_router.dart';

@Component(
...
directives: [
    ...
    routerDirectives,
  ],
)
class MyComponent {
  final RouterState _route;


  MyComponent(this._route);

  final year = this.route.queryParameters['year'];
  ...
}
```

Hope this helps